# Multi-variable integral substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

When switching to polar coordinates while working with integrals, we use $dx\,dy=r\,dr\,d\theta$ and $x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta)$. Differentiating $x$ and $y$, we get $$dx=\cos(\theta)\,dr-r\sin(\theta)\,d\theta,\quad dy=\,\sin(\theta)\,dr+r\,cos(\theta)\,d\theta.$$
Multiplying these, we get $$dx\,dy=\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)\,dr^2+r(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta))\,dr\,d\theta-r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\,d\theta^2.$$
I'm fairly certain that in integration the terms with a squared differential will equal $0$, leaving us with $dx\,dy=r(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta))dr\,d\theta$. Why is this not right? I understand how to arrive at the correct answer using the Jacobian determinant, but if the proof for multi-variable substitution is not based upon this, how can it be proven?

Comment: If I remember well, $\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$ is actually an exterior product: $\;\mathrm dx\wedge\mathrm dy$, and $\; \mathrm dr\wedge\mathrm dr=0$ by definition of the exterior product.

Comment: @Bernard I might not have thought this through, but if this is true why does fubinis theorem allow swapping of differentials without changing sign?

Comment: When you multiply differentials, you really have to think of what you're doing. What does it mean? What are you doing? What rules do they obey? Short answer -- mathematicians have found that $$\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\ne \mathrm dy\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: @Allawonder how would one go about showing this? I never knew my understanding of the differential was this flawed. I thought that fubinis theorem was sufficient evidence that operators were commutative but I guess the integrals affect what’s going on too.

Comment: @uhhhhidk Well, that's just an algebraic reformulation of what's going on, when you formally multiply differentials. This is usually called the wedge product under the topic of differential forms, and is simply introduced as a definition. The only motivation I can think of is that it works to give us results we can verify independently. Thus we may be confident that this is one of the rules of the algebra of differentials.